# php/mysql how to change and organize the value of fields after update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like image called massage (eg)

```
id | position | name
1  | 1 | name 1
2  | 2 | name 2
3  | 3 | name 3
4  | 4 | name 4
```

So when I update, edit or create a new record, I would like the table to update the column position as follow. (eg. updating the row id=1, column position from 1 to 3.)

```
id | position | name
1  | 3 | name 1
2  | 1 | name 2
3  | 2 | name 3
4  | 4 | name 4
```

I figured out how to delete a row and create a new one.
But couldnt find out how to update in the right order.
I am using a php code as this:

--- `mysql_query("UPDATE`massage`SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= '$position'"); ---`

 before the insert statement and it works fine and return as. if insert id=5 with the position 2.

```
id | position | name
1  | 1 | name 1
2  | 3 | name 2
3  | 4 | name 3
4  | 5 | name 4
5  | 2 | name 4
```

Hope someone could help me to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my question, I am posting here so if someone looking for something similar can check it out.
Here is the code to update table.
In the example table name massage. the variable `$old_position` is a select statement to check using where clause by id. the variable `$position` comes from form and relates to a new position.

```
if($old_position > $position)
{                               
    mysql_query("UPDATE `massage` SET position = position + 1 WHERE position BETWEEN '$position' AND '$old_position'");
}

if($old_position < $position)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE `massage` SET position = position - 1 WHERE position BETWEEN '$old_position' AND '$position'");
}

mysql_query("UPDATE `massage` SET position = '$position', name = '$name', visible = '$visible', content = '$content', date = '$date' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Here is for delete a row and updated the position

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `massage` SET position = position - 1 WHERE position > '$position'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `massage` WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
```

And finally here is the code to insert

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `massage` SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= '$position'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `massage` (position, name, visible, content, date) VALUES ('{$position}', '{$name}', '{$visible}', '{$content}', '{$date}')");
```

Thanks to everyone took something to help around.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL will handle your update case.  You need to know the `old position`, the `new position` and the `id` to generate it.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `massage` 
        SET `position` = `position` + SIGN({$old_position} - {$new_position})
        WHERE `position` BETWEEN {$old_position} AND {$new_position}
            AND `id` <> {$id}";
```

Comment: This only works for update, Tried to insert a row it doesnt allow me to do because the triggers

Comment: Got rid of my trigger suggestion because I realized that having an UPDATE inside a BEFORE UPDATE trigger on the same table will fail

Comment: I got your example, didnt work, so tried to work on it and still not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the new position is larger or smaller than the previous position.
if the **new position is larger**, then every position between the old position and the new position must be **minus 1**

for example from position 3 to 8, you need to shift the current 4th to 8th position to be 3rd to 7th, and update the old 3rd to 8th **(update this using its id not by its position because by this moment, you have two 3rd positions)**

> 

if the **new position is smaller**, then the same thing apply, but changes are **plus 1**.

for example from position 8 to 3, you need to shift the current 3rd to 7th position to be 4th to 8th, and update the old 8th to 3rd **(update this using its id not by its position because by this moment, you have two 8th positions)**